# custom strapi api - query model involving relation

Tags: strapi

In strapi I have two collections, products & categories related to each other, i.e. a product is related to many categories.

My question is: how do I form a query like get me products of category 'keys'

The controller of this specific route is sth like:

module.exports = {

```
async index(ctx) {

    const keys = await strapi.services.product.find({ category[0].title: 'keys' });

    return keys

}
```

}

..but obviously this produces an error

Answer (score 0):

Hi @Dimitris this should work in your case.

```
async index(ctx) {

    const products = await strapi.services['product'].find({ 'categories.title': 'keys' });

    return products

}
```

Comment: Hi Anuj, in collection 'products' there is no product with title 'keys', rather it is linked to collection 'category' via field 'categories', so that a product can belong to many categories.